Culture Fair IQ Test
I took an IQ test on (https://www.psychologytoday.com/nz/tests/iq/culture-fair-iq-test) and encountered some questions which I wasn't able to solve:
.



Can anyone share their explanation for the above questions. Thanks.

Number 1 is

 Option E because if one thinks of the matrix as one going sequentially left/right up/down you can see that the shapes change position each time in the grid and never occupy a space already occupied in any of the previous tiles and so it is option E since it has all the shapes in positions which has not previously been occupied:



Number 2 is

 Option B, the logic being that per row it is these same tiles which are reoccurring (a row needs all three of them to be ‘complete’) and the third row is missing the tile represented by B:



Number 3 is

 Option A since the tiles can be grouped together like so, one vertical line of the same sort is added from the original tile and then the central shape formed in that tile is represented in the final tile:
 


Number 4 is

 Option B; the shapes can be paired off like so. Basically every shape can be paired off with another shape in the matrix which is the result of both of its sides either ‘pulled’ or ‘pushed’ horizontally as demonstrated by the green arrows:
 


